# Exit vi editor in unix

Tags: unix, ubuntu, vi

[image]

How should i exit the vi editor.
I just opened vi editor and typed shell program then im unable to exit the vi editor due to no file name so i used :saveas command and saved as mfs. Again it showing same error

Comment: did you try ESC + :q!  ?

Comment: just type escape then :q!

Comment: Try saving the file in your home directory: `:sav ~/mfs`

Answer (score 1):

To set a file name use `:w filename`

Then you can use `:wq!` or `:x` to save and quit vi.